# Control Microsoft NLB with WMI c#

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, nlb

I try to control NLB with WMI.

```
  WqlObjectQuery wql = new  WqlObjectQuery (@"SELECT * FROM MicrosoftNLB_Node");
        ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
        foreach (var obj in search.Get())
        {
          MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
        }
```

I get a error message "Invalid class"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    @"root\MicrosoftNLB",
    @"SELECT * FROM MicrosoftNLB_Node");
foreach (var obj in search.Get())
{
    MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`MicrosoftNLB_Node`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class it's part of the `Root\MicrosoftNLB` namespace, So it seems which you are not setting the namespace before to connect to the WMi service.

try this

```
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\MicrosoftNLB",wql);
```